# How to make all pages bookmarkable in a JSF Project?

Tags: jsf, java-ee-6, bookmarks, myfaces

Before I start to implement some code. I want to be sure about the techniques.

In my case, i want to be able to bookmark every page.

What should i take in account to make it possible.

In the project I will use:

- Myfaces (JSF)
- MVP
- JPA 2.0

How should i structure/start the project??

Comment: I believe you'd like to have a look at that [tutorial](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/pdf/jsf/jsf2/JSF2-View-Params.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use GET instead of POST for page-to-page navigation.

This has nothing to do with the JSF implementation used, nor the MVP (it's actually MVC) approach, nor whether you use JPA or not, let alone the project structure.

#### See also:

- [When should I use h:outputLink instead of h:commandLink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317684/when-should-i-use-houtputlink-instead-of-hcommandlink)